# Cannot bind a SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP value using ODBC with MS SQL server (HY104: Invalid precision value)

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to bind a SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP value using ODBC to DATETIME and/or TIMESTAMP columns in a MS SQL Server database and it's failing with the following error:

```
[HY104] (native 0): [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Invalid precision value
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? I am binding the value like this:

```
TIMESTAMP_STRUCT* tval = getTimestampFromSomewhere();
SQLRETURN ret = SQLBindParameter(stmt, column, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, 29, 9, tval, sizeof(TIMESTAMP_STRUCT), 0);
```

ColSize is set to 29 because according to [Column Size docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711786(v=vs.85).aspx), for the TIMESTAMP type it should be:

> 20+s (the number of characters in the yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fff...] format, where s is the seconds precision)

and seconds precision (the precision of the fraction field) is 9 because:

> The value of the fraction field is the number of billionths of a second and ranges from 0 through 999,999,999. ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714556(v=vs.85).aspx))

DecimalDigits is set to 9 because for all datetime types except SQL_TYPE_DATE it's

> The number of digits to the right of the decimal point in the seconds part of the value (fractional seconds). ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709314(v=vs.85).aspx))

According to answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518253/inserting-timestamp-value-in-sql-server), it shouldn't be possible to insert a value into a TIMESTAMP column, but it does not work with DATETIME column for me either. And IMO the problem with TIMESTAMP should happen when actually executing the command, not when just binding the values. Therefore I think this is something else.

The same code is working for TIMESTAMP column + SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP with PostgreSQL 9.2.15 (driver "PostgreSQL Unicode" 9.3.300),

and for DATETIME and TIMESTAMP columns + SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP with MySQL 5.5.50 (driver "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver" 5.3.6).

By the way, I am running Xubuntu 16.04 64bit, the SQL Server's version is 12.0.2569 (running on Windows 10) and I am using "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" version 11.0.2270.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting precision to `3` for Sql Server and its datetime columns. They only have a precision of 3. You can easily check this using SQL Server Management Studio and try to set a value with a precision higher than 3 - you will get no error, but only 3 digits of the fraction will be stored.

Note that there is `SQLDescribeParam` function, which will return information about the decimal digits and precision values for a parameter in a query: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710188(v=vs.85).aspx

Update, about the question from the comment: You have to specify the fractional part in the full range from 1 to 999'999'9999. But, if I remember this right, Sql Server for example with a precision of '3' will only accept values where the last 6 digits of the fractional part are 0s.

Sample: It will work fine for a fractional part of 111'000'000 (which would correspond to 111'000'000 / 1'000'000'000 seconds), but setting a fractional part of 111'100'000 will fail with an error about invalid fraction or similar.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to set the fractional part of `SQL_TIMESTAMP_STRUCT` to numbers in range 0-999 or can I always send the number in the full range 0-999,999,999 and the server will convert it itself?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.